# Google App Maker : How to update multiple row of a field ?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a table with filtered results.

I need to update all rows "Payé" of the table in a client script.

I know how to update the first active row of the field "Payé". But I need to update all the row of that field in one time (in a call back function)

Can you help me.

[Here is the screen shot of what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MaCv.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var rows = app.datasources.TABLE_NAME.items;
for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
   rows[i].Paye = true;
}
```